# Passando atributos de uma Servlet para uma JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde o usuário clica em um botão editar e aí abre a página de edição com os atributos do objeto já preenchido nas caixas de texto.

No meu servlet, eu estou utilizando a seguinte lógica:

```
Moto escolhida = new Moto();

try {
    MotoDao dao = new MotoDao();
    List<Moto> motos = dao.consulta();
    //monta o objeto moto a partir do id_moto
    for (Moto m : motos) {
        if (id_moto == m.getId()) {
            escolhida = m;
        }
    }

System.out.println("dados da moto: "+ escolhida.getId()+" / "+escolhida.getModelo() );
//passa os atributos da moto escolhida para a jsp

request.setAttribute("id_moto", escolhida.getId());
request.setAttribute("marca", escolhida.getMarca());
request.setAttribute("modelo", escolhida.getModelo());
request.setAttribute("potencia", escolhida.getPotencia());
request.setAttribute("ano", escolhida.getAno());
request.setAttribute("valor", escolhida.getValor());

request.getRequestDispatcher("editar.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

No meu JSP:

```
<td> ID:</td> <td>  <input type="text" name="id_moto"  value="<%request.getAttribute("id_moto"); %>" required  /></td>
```

Na teoria, isso funcionaria, mas não esta aparecendo o ID na JSP. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Haha desculpa, a verdade é que isso ai em cima não esta funcionando, ou seja, o id nao aparece na JSP

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de colocar:

```
value="<%request.getAttribute("id_moto"); %>"
```

Tente:

```
value="${id_moto}"
```

Comment: Olá isso só daria certo caso eu estivesse usando taglib...

Comment: então tenta guardar numa variavel javaScript e depois retorna essa variavel. geralmente utilizo Taglib facilita muito as coisas.

Comment: http://www.guj.com.br/t/chamando-um-getattribute-em-uma-pagina-jsp/46266/4 

Ve se te ajuda em algo.

Comment: value="<%=request.getAttribute("id_moto"); %>"


Tenta agora. acho que faltou o  =

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, na servlet ficou deste modo:

```
int id_moto = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id_moto"));
        System.out.println("Você clicou no botão editar, id da moto: " + id_moto);
        Moto escolhida = new Moto();

        try {
            MotoDao dao = new MotoDao();
            List<Moto> motos = dao.consulta();
            //monta o objeto moto a partir do id_moto
            for (Moto m : motos) {
                if (id_moto == m.getId()) {
                    escolhida = m;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("dados da moto: " + escolhida.getId() + " / " + escolhida.getModelo());

            //passa o objeto moto escolhida para a jsp
            request.setAttribute("moto", escolhida);

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("editar.jsp");

            rd.forward(request, response);
```

e na Jsp fiz o seguinte tratamento:

```
<%@page import="Model.Moto"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>

<% //estou criando uma variável do mesmo do tipo do atributo 
    Moto moto = new Moto();
    moto = (Moto) request.getAttribute("moto");
%>



<tr> <td> ID:</td> <td>  <input type="text" name="id_moto"  value="<%= moto.getId() %>"  disabled="true"   required  /></td> </tr>
```

Esta 100% funcional!

Answer (score 0):

Eis o que você usou:

```
value="<%request.getAttribute("id_moto"); %>"
```

Observe que você usou aspas duplas tanto dentro quanto fora, logo essas aspas não abrem e fecham onde você acha que iriam. Além disso, faltou o `=` após o primeiro `%`.

Se você usasse isso:

```
value='<%= request.getAttribute("id_moto"); %>'
```

Ou seja, com aspas simples por fora e com o `=`, aí sim funcionaria.